# Joomla - replace favicon in shared links

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, favicon

I was able to replace the favicon for my site without problems in both frontend and backend and when I open the browser I see my new updated favicon correctly. But when I try to share the link of my site (example: www.mysite.com) on skype or on another social network I still see the joomla icon. Why?

I've already cleaned up all the cache but to no avail

Thanks

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, you may like to join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange as well.

Answer (score 0):

Social media have their own caches, you need to wait a few days for them to pick it up.

Just to be on the safe side, ensure your root `favicon.ico` has been updated to the new graphics, as it's the default file and some servers may take longer to process any `<link` tags specifying an alternate location.

Once that's done, just sit back and relax, 2-3 days should be enough for them to update your icon.